# Почему происходит удаление канала, даже если в нем уже есть человек?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Почему этот код удаляет канал, даже если в нем есть человек?

Мне нужно написать код, который будет создавать новый ГК, с названием: (имя пользователя)'s channel и перекидывал пользователя в новосозданный канал. Также, как только кол-во людей в канале становилось равным 0, то он самоуничтожался. Но почему-то бот удаляет канал, практически сразу, после его создания.

Пробовал сделать задержку через `time.sleep(5)`, потому что подумал, что бот считает кол-во людей только тогда, когда, у пользователя внизу написано: "голосовая связь подключена".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    target_channel_id = 1234567890
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None and after.channel.id == target_channel_id:
        overwrites = {
            member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True),
            member.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False)
        }
        channel = await after.channel.category.create_voice_channel(name=f"{member.name}'s Channel", overwrites=overwrites)
        await member.move_to(channel)
    elif before.channel is not None and before.channel.id == target_channel_id and len(before.channel.members) == 0:
        for channel in before.channel.category.voice_channels:
            if channel.name == f"{member.name}'s Channel":
                await channel.delete()
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов.
Можно, конечно, сделать и задержку через

```
await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Ну или же проще поставить флаг каналу, и его менять, если в него зайдут люди. И при удалении делать проверку, что в канал хоть раз заходили люди( Наш флаг)

Comment: Твои варианты тоже не помогают.

Comment: Что именно? Как канал может удалиться при второй реализации, если он не пройдёт проверку, что в нём хоть раз кто-то был